# Image.open() cannot identify image file in python script file

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am trying to execute this script

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image.jpg")
nx, ny = im.size
```

It is working fine when I run it in python shell

```
pytesser_v0.0.1]#env python
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open("image.jpg")
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=46x24 at 0x7FA4688F16D0>
```

but when I put it in a some test.py file and run it like **python test.py**
I am getting this error

```
File "test1.py", line 17, in <module>
    im = Image.open("image.jpg")
  File "/usr/local/python.2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2309, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file 'image.jpg'
```

please help me with this issue, Thanks

PS: Earlier I installed PIL from Imaging-1.1.7 setup.py, later I installed Pillow, I think the problem was in the mutual presence of the PIL and Pillow library on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like PIL library haven't fixed this bug yet.

Here is my solution:
Open image using OpenCV library, then convert it to PIL image

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2

image_path = 'Folder/My_picture.jpg'

# read image using cv2 as numpy array
cv_img = cv2.imread(image_path) 

# convert the color (necessary)
cv_img = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 

# read as PIL image in RGB
pil_img = Image.fromarray(cv_img).convert('RGBA')
```

Then you can operate with it as with a regular PIL image object.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "image.jpg" is in the same directory as "test1.py".

If it isn't then you could either move it, or put the correct directory inside of `Image.open()`.

Comment: image.jpg is in the same path as test1.py and I even tried giving absolute path of image.jpg but the issue is same

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

This is because the test.py does not have the same pathname. If you are working in the same folder it will work.

However, the solution i found was to put in the **full path + file name** so that it is unambiguous.

```
"c:\...fullpath...\image.jpg"
```

You can do it like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

curDir = os.getcwd()
fileName = "image.jpg"
fn = curDir + "\\" + fileName

print(fn)

image = Image.open(fn)
image.show()
```

This works. Please let me know if you find better.

Comment: Note that @Navakanth comment on the other answer that he already tried to give absolute path

Comment: You have to make sure that the absolute path works for your operating system. The example i gave was for windows10.  The reason i say this is because the \ or / were not read properly when i first tried.  The above will work on win10 but may not on ios or linux.